# How to improve Sorting performance on a None-Virtualized DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I am sure most of you would now be surprised why we had to turn off the Virtualization for the wpf datagrid.  While its true that virtualization helps to reduce memory footprint, it adds up CPU overhead and the scrolling experience is not flawless.

Due our client's request, we had to disable the virtualization in the datagrid and optimize it further and now it scrolls very smoothly up and down without any lag.  The disadvantage is that the data is pre-loaded and kept in memory.  This is a solution we can live with.

However the sorting has now become a big problem. While it's true that using a CustomSorter : IComparer would be a better sorting alternative to the usual SortDecriptors, it barely makes any difference in our case though as the whole rows are being redrawn.

Is there any way to improve sorting speed on a non-virtualized datagrid?

Highly appreciated,

**UPDATE:**

I have come across an idea, which I am trying to implement. Unbinding the Itemssource, do the sorting and once the sorting is finished, rebind the Itemssource.

In order to achieve this I am deriving from DataGrid to capture the SortHandler (that is when the column is clicked by the user)

```
public class CustomSortDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        public CustomSortDataGrid()
        {
            Sorting += SortHandler;
        }

        private void SortHandler(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridColumn column = e.Column;
            IComparer comparer = null;

            // prevent the built-in sort from sorting
            e.Handled = true;

            ListSortDirection direction = (column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

            //set the sort order on the column
            column.SortDirection = direction;

            //use a ListCollectionView to do the sort.
            var lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource);


            comparer = new BidYieldComparer(direction);

            //apply the sort
            lcv.CustomSort = comparer;

        }
    }
```

This would utilize the faster Comparer Sorting that is superior to the SortDescriptors.
Now teh question is at what stage do I unbind the items sort, apply the sorting, wait for the sorting, once event (which one?) fires then rebind the Itemssource to the view.

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(this, ItemsSourceProperty);
```

This line above would clear the binding.

```
//apply the sort
            lcv.CustomSort = comparer;
```

And theoretically (unsure if this is the right way) ItemsSource = lcv; would rebind it.  But the performance is still the same.  :(

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Implement paging in your grid :) How much data are you showing? Some third party grids are very fast at sorting, if the budget permits you should at least trial them.

Comment: Microsoft WPF Datagrid is widely underrated. We have switched from Xceed to the latter, because you couldn't disable Virtualization in Xceed. We needed an Excel experience and most third parties aren't fast enough to deal with that. Not even Infragistics.  Paging wouldnt work either, as it takes away the scroll capability.

Answer (score 1):

Try to sort your collection first then bind the sorted collection to your DataGrid. The speed of sorting operation depends on the sorting algorithm that you will use. I used to use **Insertion sort algorithm** you can read about that algorithm in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort . I will send you an example soon.

**Update**

you can find the `VB.Net` implementation [here](http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.com/2011/07/sort-any-collection-by-certain-property_05.html)

you can find the `C#` implementation [here](http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.com/2011/07/sort-any-collection-by-certain-property.html)

Comment: you can use the code that written in VB.Net      http://miroprocessor.blogspot.com/2011/05/sort-any-collection-by-certain-property.html

Comment: Hi Thanks. But how is this algorithm faster than the IComparer?

Comment: @Kave from two years ago I want to sort a huge and very complicated collection, I tried many solutions including IComparer, but the best time is when I used insertion sort algorithm.

Comment: @Kave if this help, please choose it as answer or at least vote it up, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have to implement and test this first if it even works for me. As its in VB.net it is not so easy for me to comprehend. I will come back to your post if I succeed. Thanks

Comment: @Kave you can use this http://converter.telerik.com/ to convert VB.Net to c# and I will convert it to C# as soon as possible. you are welcome

Comment: @Kave this is a C# version of my code, I hope help you. http://miroprocessor.blogspot.com/2011/06/sort-any-collection-by-certain-property.html

Comment: Thanks Miro. I have converted it now, however the code doesn't work for me yet. I am still working on it, but everytime I try to sort, nothing happens and my collection simply doubles. I get in fact an exception (that get swallowed by the try & catch) whenever I try to insert the tempRow into the collection. My collection is an observable collection. How about yours? many Thanks

Comment: my code sort generic collection by simple data type if you want to sort it by other data type, LINQ may be best choice but not best performance.that may contain helpful information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: Will have to continue the research next week. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the performance issue here is not the sorting but the binding and re-binding itself.

Just clear the binding and re-bind your grid. You should not see a big difference compared to sorting.

If this is the case, you can try to simplify your templates and styles for that grid, if you are using any.